# I can't scrape div parameters of the website (scrapy)

Tags: python, html, web-scraping, scrapy

I'm using scrapy to get information of this [website](http://guia.bcn.cat/index.php?pg=search&q=*:*)

The code that I want scrape has the following structure:

```
<div id="llista-resultats">
 <div>
  <h3>
   <a href="URL"> Title </a>
  <div class="dades">
   <dl>
    <dt> </dt>
    <dd> </dd>
    ...
  </div>
 <div>
  And repetar again
```

I have done tests and I know how to get the information, but the problem that I have with the following code is that I get all the titles, then all the URLs, etc and that I want is select the first title with the first URL.

```
class BcnSpider(CrawlSpider):
    name = 'bcn'
    allowed_domains = ['guia.bcn.cat']
    start_urls = ['http://guia.bcn.cat/index.php?pg=search&q=*:*']

    def parse(self, response):
    sel = Selector(response)
    sites = sel.xpath("//div[@id='llista-resultats']")
    items = []
    for site in sites:
        item = BcnItem()
        item['title'] = site.xpath("//div[@id='llista-resultats']//h3/a/text()").extract()
        item['url'] = site.xpath("//div[@id='llista-resultats']//h3/a/@href").extract()
        item['when'] = site.xpath("//div[@id='llista-resultats']//div[@class='dades']/dl/dd/text()").extract()
        items.append(item)
    return items
```

I think that the error is because I'm using `//` on each item, but i didn't achived get information that is descendant of `sites = sel.xpath("//div[@id='llista-resultats']")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [relative xpath selectors](http://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/selectors.html#topics-selectors-nesting-selectors) for nested properties

Also you didn't specify selector for sites right way.

```
sites = sel.xpath("//div[@id='llista-resultats']/div")
items = []
for site in sites:
    item = BcnItem()
    item['title'] = site.xpath("h3/a/text()").extract()
    item['url'] = site.xpath("h3/a/@href").extract()
    item['when'] = site.xpath("div[@class='dades']/dl/dd/text()").extract()
    items.append(item)
return items
```

Answer (score 0):

try this :
dont use `//` after the first selector i.e format the string like

```
item['title'] = site.xpath("//div[@id='llista-resultats']/h3/a/text()").extract()
item['url'] = site.xpath("//div[@id='llista-resultats']/h3/a/@href").extract()
item['when'] = site.xpath("//div[@id='llista-resultats']/div[@class='dades']/dl/dd/text()").extract()
    items.append(item)
return items
```

Comment: If i do that i get no results: 
{'title':[], 'url':[], 'when':[]}